# Using T-SQL XML input element values for an IN Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to write a procedure to sync users from Active directory into my local application database.  From my code, I'm passing XML in the following format to the stored procedure:

```
<AdUsers>
  <AdUser AccountSid="S-1-5-21-111111111-111111111-111111111-1111" DisplayName="Test User" EmailAddress="tuser@mail.local" ExchangeServerFk="4" ExchangeServer="https://mail.local" Department="" StatusFK="1" UserName="TUSER">
    <AccountSids>
      <Sid>S-1-5-21-111111111-111111111-111111111-1111</Sid>
    </AccountSids>
  </AdUser>
</AdUsers>
```

I'd like to do a sync between the XML and the rows in my tb_Mailboxes table with the following Stored Procedure:

```
@adUsers XML, @lastSyncBy VARCHAR (50), @lastSyncOn DATETIME, @defaultProfileId INT, @adDomainId INT
AS

begin try
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        --First delete all the mailboxes exist in the database but not in the xml.
        delete tb_Mailboxes
        where AccountSid not in (
            select 
                 rtrim(element.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(100)')) as AccountSid
            from 
                @adUsers.nodes('/AdUsers/AdUser/AccountSids/Sid') t(element)


        ) AND @adDomainId = AdDomainFk

        --Then insert or update existing accounts
        MERGE tb_Mailboxes as [target]
        USING 
        (
            select 
                 rtrim(element.value('data(@AccountSid)', 'varchar(100)')) as AccountSid
                ,rtrim(element.value('data(@DisplayName)', 'varchar(100)')) as DisplayName
                ,rtrim(element.value('data(@EmailAddress)', 'varchar(500)')) as EmailAddress
                ,rtrim(element.value('data(@ExchangeServerFk)', 'varchar(100)')) as ExchangeServerFk
                ,rtrim(element.value('data(@ExchangeServer)', 'varchar(150)')) as ExchangeServer
                ,rtrim(element.value('data(@Department)', 'varchar(100)')) as Department
                ,rtrim(element.value('data(@StatusFK)', 'varchar(100)')) as StatusFK
                ,rtrim(element.value('data(@UserName)', 'varchar(100)')) as UserName
                ,element.query('AccountSids') as SidList
            from 
                @adUsers.nodes('/AdUsers/AdUser') t(element)
        ) as [source] 
             on [target].AccountSid IN
             (
                SELECT rtrim(A.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(100)')) as CurSid 
                FROM [source].SidList.nodes('Sid') AS FN(A)
             )
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
            DisplayName = [source].DisplayName
            ,EmailAddress = [source].EmailAddress
            ,ExchangeServerFk = [source].ExchangeServerFk
            ,ExchangeServer = [source].ExchangeServer
            ,Department = [source].Department
            ,UserName = [source].UserName   
            /*,StatusFK = [source].StatusFK*/
            ,LastSyncOn = @lastSyncOn
            ,LastSyncBy = @lastSyncBy
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 
            (
                AdDomainFk, 
                UserName, 
                DisplayName, 
                Department, 
                EmailAddress, 
                ExchangeServerFk, 
                ExchangeServer, 
                AccountSid, 
                IsAutoDeleteEnabled, 
                ProfileFk, 
                Settings, 
                QueueLastPickedUp, 
                QueueLastProcessed, 
                QueueLastFinished, 
                LastSyncOn, 
                LastSyncBy,
                StatusFK
            )
            VALUES
            (
            @adDomainId
            ,[source].UserName
            ,[source].DisplayName
            ,[source].Department
            ,[source].EmailAddress
            ,[source].ExchangeServerFk
            ,[source].ExchangeServer
            ,[source].AccountSid
            ,0
            ,@defaultProfileId
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
            ,NULL
            ,@lastSyncOn
            ,@lastSyncBy
            ,[source].StatusFK
            );

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

However, the "NOT IN" in the delete section AND "IN" in the match section don't seem to work.  Is this type of IN clause using multiple values in the XML even feasible?  Is there a better approach to this problem that I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry for the edit problems.  The post should be readable now.

Comment: When doing a TRANSACTION (for Insert/Update/Delete or Merge(Upsert)/Delete), I like to shred the xml into a @ variable or # temp table and then being the TRAN.  That way the shredding takes place outside of the TRAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your MERGE query is the join between the [source] and the [target] tables. Rather than joining the target and source tables using

```
     ON [target].AccountSid IN
     (
        SELECT rtrim(A.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(100)')) as CurSid 
        FROM [source].SidList.nodes('Sid') AS FN(A)
     )
```

use this instead:

```
    ON [target].AccountSid = [source].AccountSid
```

[source] will be materialised as a table and you join to it like you would any other table. Your IN statement doesn't make much sense as it is a completely different entity so will equivalent to a kind of Cartesian join (FULL OUTER).

Another comment I would make is why the separate DELETE statement to remove mailboxes that no longer exist in the XML? Why not simply put the DELETE within the MERGE statement by using the following statement?

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
               THEN DELETE
```

Applying all this, your MERGE statement becomes:

```
MERGE tb_Mailboxes AS [target]
    USING 
        (SELECT RTRIM(element.value('data(@AccountSid)', 'varchar(100)')) AS AccountSid
              , RTRIM(element.value('data(@DisplayName)', 'varchar(100)')) AS DisplayName
              , RTRIM(element.value('data(@EmailAddress)', 'varchar(500)')) AS EmailAddress
              , RTRIM(element.value('data(@ExchangeServerFk)', 'varchar(100)')) AS ExchangeServerFk
              , RTRIM(element.value('data(@ExchangeServer)', 'varchar(150)')) AS ExchangeServer
              , RTRIM(element.value('data(@Department)', 'varchar(100)')) AS Department
              , RTRIM(element.value('data(@StatusFK)', 'varchar(100)')) AS StatusFK
              , RTRIM(element.value('data(@UserName)', 'varchar(100)')) AS UserName
         FROM   @adUsers.nodes('/AdUsers/AdUser') t (element)) AS [source]
    ON [target].AccountSid = [source].AccountSid
    WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN UPDATE
           SET      DisplayName = [source].DisplayName
                  , EmailAddress = [source].EmailAddress
                  , ExchangeServerFk = [source].ExchangeServerFk
                  , ExchangeServer = [source].ExchangeServer
                  , Department = [source].Department
                  , UserName = [source].UserName   
        /*,StatusFK = [source].StatusFK*/
                  , LastSyncOn = @lastSyncOn
                  , LastSyncBy = @lastSyncBy
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT (AdDomainFk
                   , UserName
                   , DisplayName
                   , Department
                   , EmailAddress
                   , ExchangeServerFk
                   , ExchangeServer
                   , AccountSid
                   , IsAutoDeleteEnabled
                   , ProfileFk
                   , Settings
                   , QueueLastPickedUp
                   , QueueLastProcessed
                   , QueueLastFinished
                   , LastSyncOn
                   , LastSyncBy
                   , StatusFK)
           VALUES   (@adDomainId
                   , [source].UserName
                   , [source].DisplayName
                   , [source].Department
                   , [source].EmailAddress
                   , [source].ExchangeServerFk
                   , [source].ExchangeServer
                   , [source].AccountSid
                   , 0
                   , @defaultProfileId
                   , NULL
                   , NULL
                   , NULL
                   , NULL
                   , @lastSyncOn
                   , @lastSyncBy
                   , [source].StatusFK)
     WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
         THEN DELETE;
```